# A data structure that supports efficient insertion of arbitrary integers, value lookup, and removal of all integers smaller than a given threshold?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure that supports efficient:

1. Insertion of arbitrary integers.
2. Value lookup (given a particular value `needle`, return true if it's currently in the structure).
3. Removal of all values below a given `threshold` integer.

I suspect this can be with a [self-balancing BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), with insertion and lookup both costing `log(n)` time. I *think* the removal operation can be done by pruning an entire subtree out, but I'm not sure this can be done in `log(n)` time while keeping the tree balanced. If we remove a very large subtree (say the left child of the root node), it seems like it would take basically rebuilding the entire tree, which is `O(m log m)` with `m` being the number of remaining nodes, and at any rate no less than `O(m)`.

A cheaper approach would be to use a naturally-ordered self-balancing BST. For removal, we can just start at the smallest node, and keep removing (and rebalancing) until we run out of nodes or hit the `threshold`. This will cost `O(m log n)` where `m` is the number of nodes to be removed.

Bonus question: what if instead of removing below a `threshold`, we need to support removal of all nodes in a range between `upper_bound` and `lower_bound`?

Comment: Is there a bound on (the absolute values of) all numbers? Have you considered (lazy) segment tree? Do you require an online algorithm?

Comment: @JohnL. let's say all numbers are 32-bit unsigned `ints`. This needs to be an online algorithm. I don't know about segment trees but I'll read up on them if they are the best solution here.

Comment: you can try using a splay tree with amortized logn complexity perhaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accept randomized algorithms you could use [TREAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap). This data structure is BST where each node is augmented with *priority*, a random number. The only one invariant over normal normal BST is that parent's priority must be greater than children's. This results in a very simple implementation of *Insert* and *Delete* functions (recursive variant is 10-15 lines of clean C code).
The complexity of basic operations is $O(\log N)$ on average.

It is possible to cut-off all nodes below *threshold* in $O(\log n)$ time assuming that nodes below the *threshold* are not disposed.

```
Node cut(Node node, int threshold) {
   if (node->key < threshold) {
      // optionally dispose node, and subtree at node->left
      return cut(node->right, threshold);
   }
   node->left = cut(node->left, threshold);
   return node;
}

root = cut(root, threshold);
```

Note, that there is no rebalancing because the node is replaced by one of its children (or subchildren). As result the priority invariant in satisfied.

Disposal of nodes with a key below the threshold will increase complexity to $O(k + \log n)$, where $k$ is a number of disposed nodes.
Cost of disposal will be amortized to $O(1)$ over multiple operations because each node is created and disposed only once.

Removal of nodes *above* a given threshold will require symmetrical functions.

Comment: What do you mean by "assuming that excluding disposal of the nodes"?